# C memory bit mess

Tags: c, xilinx

I am reading from a 16-bit memory address on a 32-bit processor. For some reason I am not getting the expected output.
 Contents of the address is a 32-byte word.

```
ABCDEFABCDEFABCDABCDEFABCDEFABCD
```

Code I am using is this :

```
  u8 SendBuffer[128];
  u8 ReceiveBuffer[128];
  uint32_t InRAM1;
  int btidx=0;
  int tsize=32;
  for (Index = 0; Index <tsize; Index++) {
    int sbit=btidx*sizeof(uint32_t);
    InRAM1 = XIo_In32(RAM1_ADDR+sbit);
    u8 *v1=(u8 *)&XIo_In32(RAM1_ADDR+sbit);
    SendBuffer[Index] =  v1[Index];
    SendBuffer[Index+1] =  v1[Index+1]; 
    ReceiveBuffer[Index] = 0; 
    ReceiveBuffer[Index+1] = 0;     
    xil_printf("Data: %c%c %c%c \n\r", 
               (InRAM1 &0xff), (InRAM1 >>8)&0xff,
               SendBuffer[Index], SendBuffer[Index+1]);
    btidx++;
    Index++;
  }
```

Result after running is the following. Banging my head trying to solve this. What am I doing wrong in this ? Thanks for any help.

```
Data: AB AB 
Data: CD  
Data: EF AB 
Data: AB  
Data: CD AB 
Data: EF  
Data: AB CD 
Data: CD  
Data: AB CD 
Data: CD  
Data: EF CD 
Data: AB  
Data: CD  
Data: EF  
Data: AB  
Data: CD
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just use `XIo_In16()` to read the 16 bit memory instead of breaking the `xio.h` abstraction?

Comment: Sure. I could do that, but that doesn't solve the problem, it definitely makes it neater...

Comment: It solves the problem if you just use the value returned by the XIo function/macro instead of getting a raw pointer to the memory based on what the it returns (which, by the way, happens to work only because the `XIo_InXx()` APIs are implemented as macros that do pointer magic and not implemented as functions). Your code already gets each byte of the data in the 16-bit memory with the `InRAM1` variable - why not just use that technique (with the slight change of assigning the value to InRAM1 using the `XIo_In16()` API instead of `XIo_In32()` to access the 16-bit memory appropriately)?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBurr. I implemented your suggestion. The problem is XUartlite requires an u8 for the Send and Receive buffers, so XIo_In16 alone won't solve the problem. One would still need a conversion from uint16 to uint8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
SendBuffer[Index] = v1[0];  
SendBuffer[Index+1] = v1[1];
```

`Index` will keep incrementing and you skip bits...